# How to overwrite a file with NSFileManager when copying?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, filesystems, nsfilemanager

I'm using this method to copy a file:

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:targetPath error:&error];
```

I want to overwrite a file when it exists already. The default behavior of this method is to throw an exception/error "File Exists." when the file exists. There's no option to specify that it should overwrite.

So what would be the safest way to do this?

Would I first check if the file exists, then delete it, and then attempt to copy? This has the danger that the app or device goes OFF right in the nanosecond after the file has been deleted but the new file hasn't been copied to that place. Then there's nothing.

Maybe I would have to change the name of the new file first, then delete the old, and then re-change the name of the new? Same problem. What if in this nanosecond the app or device goes OFF and renaming doesn't happen?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'd want to do an **atomic save** in this case, which would be best achieved by using `NSData` or `NSString`'s `writeToFile:atomically:` methods (and their variants):

```
NSData *myData = ...; //fetched from somewhere
[myData writeToFile:targetPath atomically:YES];
```

Or for an `NSString`:

```
NSString *myString = ...;
NSError *err = nil;
[myString writeToFile:targetPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
if(err != nil) {
  //we have an error.
}
```

Comment: What if you don't want to load the entire file into RAM (due to it being large)? Loading the file seems like it could be somewhat inefficient.

Comment: @NickForge You *could* use `NSFileManager`'s `-moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` method.

Comment: @JacobRelkin This method does not override existing files so it cannot be used.

Comment: Agreed, but is it atomic?

Answer (score 55):

If you can't/don't want to keep the file contents in memory but want an atomic rewrite as noted in the other suggestions, you can first copy the original file to a temp directory to a unique path (Apple's documentation suggests using a temporary directory), then use NSFileManager's

`-replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:`

According to the reference documentation, this method 'replaces the contents of the item at the specified URL in a manner that insures no data loss occurs.' (from reference documentation). The copying of the original to the temporary directory is needed because this method moves the original file.
[Here's the NSFileManager reference documentation about `-replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412432-replaceitematurl?language=objc)

Comment: Great answer. Upvoted. What if the file is simultaneously being processed in some way, like being sent to another app via a UIDocumentInteractionController, or being printed via AirPrint, or being uploaded to a server? Does this ensure that the second app (or the printer or the server) will get either the new file or the old one, rather than a corrupted file consisting of some bits from the new file and some bits from the old one? Or is that assumption not safe to make?

Comment: @KartickVaddadi this method gives guarantees that the file that appears at the _target_ location is placed there atomically. I am presuming that concurrent modifications to the _source_ data would sitll lead to corruption. If that is a concern, you should probably wrap operations on the source file through NSFileCoordinator / NSFilePresenter APIs – at least on iOS you should not be getting modifications from the system that aren't NSFileCoordinator proof.

Comment: I'm talking about changes to the destination, not source. I understand atomicity wrt to (say) the system losing power, but what if you have a file handle / stream open to the target file? How does atomicity affect that? Say you were uploading "a.pdf" to a server, and halfway through the upload, the file gets replaced by "b.pdf". Will the server have a.pdf, b.pdf, or a corrupt file? Likewise for printing or sharing to another app. If the answer is that it will be corrupt, should one wrap all operations on the target in file coordination?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works at least on HFS+ by replacing the inode on the filesystem, which would probably mean that attempting to write to file handles that were open until that inode replacement happened would begin failing on the file writing system calls (< guess). Uploads would be a perfect case of wanting atomic file operations because you don't want to upload in place into the final URL a file that may never finish uploading successfully. Also, as there's no filesystem locking facility, file coordination is indeed a pretty useful thing often when you have potential for multiple writers.

Answer (score 26):

If you're not sure if the file exists, this works on swift 3+

```
try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: item_destination)
try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: item, to: item_destination)
```

The first line fails and is ignored if the file doesn't already exist. If there's a exception during the second line, it throws as it should.

Comment: thank you. Replacement removed source item for me. With your suggestion it works great

Comment: If the program is terminated between two lines of code, you will not find the file in place, which may result in a large area of crash!
⚠️Don't do this in a production environment!

Answer (score 11):

Swift4:

```
_ = try FileManager.default.replaceItemAt(previousItemUrl, withItemAt: currentItemUrl)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: To add context, since this is the best answer on the page, it will replace the file if it exists, and if not will save the file there regardless. It returns the url of the new item or nil.

Comment: Meh, it might be the best answer if you're doing swift but the OP isn't coding in swift.

Answer (score 5):

Detect file exists error, delete the destination file and copy again.

Sample code in Swift 2.0:

```
class MainWindowController: NSFileManagerDelegate {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager()

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        fileManager.delegate = self
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(srcPath, toPath: dstPath)
        } catch {
            print("File already exists at \'\(srcPath)\':\n\((error as NSError).description)")
        }
    }

    func fileManager(fileManager: NSFileManager, shouldProceedAfterError error: NSError, copyingItemAtPath srcPath: String, toPath dstPath: String) -> Bool {
        if error.code == NSFileWriteFileExistsError {
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(dstPath)
                print("Existing file deleted.")
            } catch {
                print("Failed to delete existing file:\n\((error as NSError).description)")
            }
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(srcPath, toPath: dstPath)
                print("File saved.")
            } catch {
                print("File not saved:\n\((error as NSError).description)")
            }
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Swift 2.0, the better option would be to use the do/try/catch syntax instead of "try!" and using the delegate.

Answer (score 4):

For overwriting files, I prefer

```
NSData *imgDta = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tImg, 1.0);

[imgDta writeToFile:targetPath options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone error:&err];
```

Removing & copying files in loop sometimes doesn't work as intended

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the NSFileManagerDelegate protocol method:

```
- (BOOL)fileManager:(NSFileManager *)fileManager shouldProceedAfterError:(NSError *)error copyingItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath;
```

From this method, you can decide what to do with the existing file (rename/delete) and then proceed with the copy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the possibility of the nanosecond you mensioned is feeble. so stick to the first method of removing the existing file and copying the new file.

Comment: I believe that nanosecond is dependent on the size of data being written to disk ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is for improvement of 'Swift 3 and above' of question '[Move file and override [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295555/move-file-and-override?noredirect=1&lq=1)' which is marked duplicate of this question.

To move file from sourcepath(string) to DestinationPath(string).
Delete the existing file if same name file already exists at DestinationPath.

```
// Set the correct path in string in 'let' variables.
let destinationStringPath = ""
let sourceStringPath = ""

let fileManager:FileManager = FileManager.default
do
{
    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: sourceStringPath)
}
catch
{
}

do
{
    try fileManager.moveItem(atPath: sourceStringPath, toPath: destinationStringPath)
}
catch
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code ensures that the copy will succeed without file corruption or loss, **even if the application is terminated at any time**.

```
if try FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: target.path) == true {
    try fileManager.replaceItemAt(target, withItemAt: source)
}
```