# Save NSData always to the same file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata

I want to save each `NSData` object to a temp directory in iOS and I want each new object to overwrite the old one.

Objects will be of different formats and of different sizes.

I know how do you get the path to the `NSTemporaryDirectory` but how on Earth can you overwrite old `NSData` file in there each time a new one is added?

Comment: Take a look at this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6137471/1075405

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the file.

Remove it from `NSTemporaryDirectory`.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
```

Create a new file with same name and save it there.

```
[[NSData data] writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
```

---

Or Simply you can over-write the file.

```
NSData *data = <all data>;
[data writeToFile:targetPath atomically:YES];
```