# How to overwrite a folder using [NSFileManager defaultManager] when copying?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

Using the line below,

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:targetPath error:&error];
```

We can copy a folder but if the folder already exists it throws an exception "File Exists".
In order to overwrite a single file, we can achieve it through the following lines:

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:FileURL]; /fetch single file
[myData writeToFile:targetPath atomically:YES];
```

But I want to copy  an already existing folder i.e, **overwrite**.

**Edit** :
Simple Possibility , I can remove the items before copying them.

Please suggest any more possibilities.

Comment: please check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137423/how-to-overwrite-a-file-with-nsfilemanager-when-copying

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default behavior of `NSFileManager` method is to throw an exception/error "File Exists." when the file exists. But still if you want to overwrite using `NSFileManager` then it provides one api for that which is mentioned below [replaceItemAtURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:) as well in first solution:-

Also there are three solutions to achieve that

**First Solution**

```
[filemanger replaceItemAtURL:url1 
               withItemAtURL:url2
              backupItemName:@"/Users/XYZ/Desktop/test.xml"
                     options:NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly 
            resultingItemURL:nil error:nil];
```

Using the above API you can overwrite the file contents. But before that you have to take the backup of your source path in your temporary directory.

**Second Solution**

Already you have mentioned in your question using `NSData writeToUrl`.

**Third Solution**

trojanfoe has mentioned in [their answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683834/1032372) i.e. remove the item being overwritten beforehand.

Comment: Sorry for accepting with (huge) delay . came back after long break.Perhaps, this bounty will compensate :)

Answer (score 9):

I would like to add one more using delegate, in order to override files with copyItemAtPath (NSFileManager) function use:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setDelegate:self];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:fileOrigin toPath:fileDestin error:&error];
```

and implement the delegates optional function:

```
 - (BOOL)fileManager:(NSFileManager *)fileManager shouldProceedAfterError:(NSError *)error copyingItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath{
    if ([error code] == NSFileWriteFileExistsError) //error code for: The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the item first, with:

```
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:targetPath error:NULL];
```

(i.e. ignoring any error)

Comment: Thanks for your response . For copying my folder it consumes around 10 secs in device.Then, here in my case , If I delete the same , then Operation time will be doubled.

Comment: -1: Why would you ignore the error? What if you don't have permission to remove the item? At the very least it should be logged to the console.

Comment: @CraigOtis It will be caught by the next line of code (provided by the OP).

Comment: @itechnician Are you sure it will *double* the time taken?  I very much doubt that.

Comment: @trojanfoe Accurately it wont take 2x (Approx 1.7~~1.98x time) time But I am sure that it will take less time (Approx 1.2~~1.4x time) incase  it gets overwritten. Thanks again for your consideration

Comment: Well, perhaps you could copy your original folder to a place besides the folder to be replaced, then rename both folders (effectively swapping them), the unlink the old, replaced folder.. I wonder if that would be faster?

Comment: Another option would be to recursively copy from source to destination only replacing outdated files. Maybe this would be faster? You will have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
```

Comment: Please explain something what it is doing?

Comment: first check that file exist or not & if yes then remove file. this will ignoring error --- use  after  [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:targetPath error:&error];