# Move file and override

Tags: ios, swift, file, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to move a file even if a file with the same name already exists.

```
NSFileManager().moveItemAtURL(location1, toURL: location2)
```

Does `NSFileManager`'s method `moveItemAtURL` have an override option?  How can I replace the existing file?

Comment: Delete the destination file and then do the move.

Comment: theres a lot of objc answers to this question. you might be able to convert some of those answers to swift, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137423/how-to-overwrite-a-file-with-nsfilemanager-when-copying and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683696/how-to-overwrite-a-folder-using-nsfilemanager-defaultmanager-when-copying

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always check if the file exists in the target location.
if it does, delete it and move your item.

**Swift 2.3**

```
let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(location2) 
{
  do
  {
    try filemgr.moveItemAtURL(location1, toURL: location2)
  }
  catch
  {
  }
}
else
{
  do
  {
    try filemgr.removeItemAtPath(location2)
    try filemgr.moveItemAtURL(location1, toURL: location2)
  }
  catch
  {

  }
}
```

**Swift 3+**

```
try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: location2)
try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location1, to: location2)
```

Comment: would this not be more concise: `if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(location2) 
{
  do
  {
    try filemgr.removeItemAtPath(location2)
  }
  catch
  {
  }
}

  do
  {
    try filemgr.moveItemAtURL(location1, toURL: location2)
  }
  catch
  {

  }`

Comment: For 'Swift 3 and above', you may check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49854283/2641380             as we can not answer it here.