# NSFileManager moving a file shows error

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I am trying to create two log files and replace content in the second file with the content in the first file.

My code for creating log in AppDelegate

```
   NSArray *paths3 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory3 = [paths3 objectAtIndex:0];
       logPath3 = [documentsDirectory3 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console4.log"];

        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:logPath3])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:logPath3 contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil];

        NSLog(@"path %@",logPath3);

        freopen([logPath3 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);

 NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory2 = [paths2 objectAtIndex:0];
        logPath2 = [documentsDirectory2 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console3.log"];

        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:logPath2])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:logPath2 contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil];

        NSLog(@"path %@",logPath2);

        freopen([logPath2 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
        _isFileOneCreated =YES;
```

code to move content

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError * err;
if ([filemgr moveItemAtPath:
     logPath2 toPath:
   logPath3 error: &err])
    NSLog (@"Day 3 Move successful");
else
    NSLog (@"Day 3 Move failed  %@",[err localizedDescription]);
```

But i get an error 516.

```
   (Cocoa error 516.)" UserInfo=0x16dba220    {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/274E9843-2C8E-45F3-BD41-EA392F50C7AC/Documents/console3.log, NSUserStringVariant=(
Move
), NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/274E9843-2C8E-45F3-BD41-EA392F50C7AC/Documents/console3.log, NSDestinationFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/274E9843-2C8E-45F3-BD41-EA392F50C7AC/Documents/console4.log, NSUnderlyingError=0x16da63f0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}
```

Help me solve my issue

Comment: Well what do you expect when you use two different ways of getting the paths?

Comment: You can't just start out using "Documents/...". Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272544/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-documents-directory-on-an-iphone).

Comment: @borrrden help me mate i am new with file manager

Comment: Do the same thing you did in the first chunk of code to get the directory again

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: @vishnuvarthan You already posted the code, use the same thing. Look at `paths2` to see what we mean.

Comment: Please post the logs too. Did that work?

Comment: Day 3 Move failed  The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.) @rebello95 .This also did not work

Comment: Check the contents of _Document_ directory; error says _file_ _exist_ which explains as _moveItemAtPath_ will abort the move operation if file is present at destination path, you may want to keep a check for that. If file exist, reset your simulator and try again.

Comment: Yes i have both the files already created and also has some content in  both file(device logs).I need to replace the content @Gandalf

Comment: you did open console2.log so fclose it before move.

Comment: What is _logPath1_ in file movement code? Your error contains file name as _console3.log_ and _console4.log_, which i do not see in your code. Assuming that you want file1 to be overwritten by file2 you are doing a mistake as you are having both the file in same directory and then you want resulting file to be overwritten. So final scenario is like having 2 file with same name at same location. That's why the error. Remove the destination file and move the source file to new path.

Comment: @Gandalf see the edited code. Giving a sample code will be more helpfull

Comment: So if you want to save your logs for 30 days can I assume you'll have 30 identical chunks of code, each performing (mostly) the same thing?  I think you need to learn about loops.

Comment: @Droppy i need all the recent 30 days files at any point of time  so i need to have the recent thirty day files,which means i need to store thirty files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*moveItemAtPath* does not allow you to overwrite the file with same name. See this [Question Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137423/how-to-overwrite-a-file-with-nsfilemanager-when-copying).

All you need to do is **delete** the file at target location before you overwrite with new one. Use the below code. This will do the trick but i advice you to take precaution to have the backup of your file just in case *move* doesn't work for some unknown reason.

```
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];   
NSError * err;  
[filemgr removeItemAtPath:logPath3 error:&err];  
if ([filemgr moveItemAtPath:logPath3 toPath:logPath2 error: &err])   
   NSLog (@"Day 3 Move successful");  
else   
   NSLog (@"Day 3 Move failed  %@",[err localizedDescription]);
```